# How do I get my files from my Windows machine to my Ubuntu web server for development?

Tags: apache2, ftp, web-development

My Win8 machine has Dreamweaver etc. installed. This devices is mainly used for development. Instead of saving the files to a shared, hosted server I wanted to save and test them locally first and then upload them so I have 3 dev-stages for website: development, beta, production.

So I bought a small machine and installed Lubuntu. It runs great, afaik, and is connected to my network. I can access the device with VNC and SSH and it is perfectly reachable via IP-Address in the browser.

However, I can't figure out how to handle the development part. Or simpler:

**How do I get my file from my Windows machine to my Linux (Web-Server) while development?**

The files should be stored in realtime, e.g. I want to work on the server directly.

**My possible solution:**

- Network-Sharing the /var/www folder > not allowed, only for root, does not seem to be nice solution
- Setting up a /www folder in /home and share the folder > how to include this to apache/php?
- Using FTP > why (and how) should I use FTP if the server is attached to my local network?

I googled for hours but I can't find anything that doesn't sound "quick and dirty" (like changing permissions on /var/www).

I've set up:

- Lubuntu
- Apache2, PHP5, MySQL
- Installed PhpMyAdmin

**So, what is the best solution?**

some edits:
As I was totally new to the linux world I did not fully understand permission/user/group system. I managed to install vsftpd and the ftp-user is now allowed to write into the apache /var/www folder (what I think is a really nice solution).

WebDav (from the comments) also sounds nice. For now I will go with the FTP solution - it's super fast and works, but the question is still open, what is the best solution?

Comment: FTP using WebDAV, using an Apache virtual host with a directory somewhere other than /var/www that you have permissions to read/write. Mount the WebDAV volume and work from there.

Comment: If you are looking for the "best" is too subjective. I say that you should stick with FTP if it works for you (I would harden it with FTP + SSH/SSL).

Comment: Dreamweaver supports FTP/SFTP sites, last i checked... you could use Dreamweaver to just manage the data on each of the sites rather than messing with an FTP client or Samba or anything...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Apache feature I found recently: the "userdir" module.

If I'm not mistaken, you can enable it by executing in the terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After this, if you create a folder named `public_html` inside your home folder, that folder will be "included" in Apache (your 2nd possible solution).
The URL to access the content in that folder from the browser is of the type `http://YOUR_SERVER_ADDRESS/~YOUR_USERNAME/`.

Example: `localhost/~ubuntu/` if your username is ubuntu.

By default, only static HTML files can be used, PHP scripts can not be used for security reasons. To enable PHP processing when using userdir:

Edit `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf` and comment out the line `php_admin_value engine Off` by putting a # before it. See below:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf

<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
  <Directory /home/*/public_html>
    #php_admin_value engine Off
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Reload apache2 using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

and test your PHP code in the userdir directory.

If you get a *permission denied* error (or similar) in the browser, make sure that the `www-data` user (I think that's the correct name) can access that folder and the files inside.
That means your home folder must have *execute* (**x**) permission for the *others* (**o**), and that the `public_html` folder must have *read* (**r**) and *write* permissions for the *others*.

You should then be able to share the `public_html` folder with the network without problems.

Comment: @Parto, thank you for the edit! That information is useful (even for me).